# Overlay two rasters and extract values from one of the rasters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.3, viewshed

I'm creating a Higuchi viewshed and I'm not sure what tool to use to do the last step.

Stages in the Generation of an Higuchi Viewshed

1. Calculate binary viewshed for viewpoint
2. Calculate a distance layer from the viewpoint
3. Reclassify the distance layer according to the Higuchi class criteria (determined by the typical tree height for the area and period under study)
4. Overlay the binary viewshed upon the distance layer to extract the distance range values which fall within the in-view zone

I've created the binary viewshed and the distance layer (using euclidean distance tool), and reclassified the distance layer.

However, I'm not sure what tool to use to extract the values from the distance layer that fall within the viewshed zone.

Example of the process:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Times tool or the Raster Calculator to multiply your classified distance raster by your binary viewshed.

Or

Use the Con tool (or the Con function in the Raster Calculator), i.e `Con(binaryviewshed, distance)`

The difference between the two operations is you'll get 0 where the binary viewshed is 0 with the first op and NoData with the 2nd op.